# Can't receive mail, but can send mail? Centos 6 Postfix/Dovecot

Tags: email, centos, gmail, postfix, dovecot

I followed this tutorial to setup my webmail on centos 6: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/mailserver-with-virtual-users-and-domains-using-postfix-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-6-vps/

Everything is setup perfect, but whenever I try to receive mail, in roundcube nothing appears. I can still compose emails in Roundcube and have others receive them.

What might I be doing wrong?

I attempted to email myself from my gmail account, and these are the logs that occur from sending an email to the server email. I x'd out the real domain, just if you are wondering.

```
Oct 12 04:26:10 vps30159 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<xxxx@xxxx.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1125, secured
Oct 12 04:26:10 vps30159 dovecot: imap(xxxx@xxxx.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=50/404
Oct 12 04:27:09 vps30159 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<xxxx@xxxx.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1136, secured
Oct 12 04:27:09 vps30159 dovecot: imap(xxxx@xxxx.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=50/404
Oct 12 04:28:09 vps30159 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<xxxx@xxxx.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1141, secured
Oct 12 04:28:09 vps30159 dovecot: imap(xxxx@xxxx.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=50/404
Oct 12 04:29:05 vps30159 postfix/anvil[1112]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:unknown) at Oct 12 04:25:45
Oct 12 04:29:05 vps30159 postfix/anvil[1112]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:unknown) at Oct 12 04:25:45
Oct 12 04:29:05 vps30159 postfix/anvil[1112]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Oct 12 04:25:45
Oct 12 04:29:09 vps30159 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<xxxx@xxxx.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=1146, secured
Oct 12 04:29:09 vps30159 dovecot: imap(xxxx@xxxx.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=50/404
```

EDIT:

I can send emails locally btw.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your /etc/postfix/master.cf configuration file and see if Postfix is configured to pass on all incoming emails to virtual users. Basically, the following lines should be present:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe

flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

They are usually located at the end of the `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file, so add them using your favorite text editor if they don't exist.

After you make the modification, restart Postfix using:

```
service postfix restart
```

You should now check your `/var/log/mail.log` file for errors, if any.

Comment: Remember to properly format your answer. Use a right angle bracket `>` before each line of a block quote, and indent code blocks with four spaces.